# React States to create external link with Window Location url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a situation where I need to put a state in my `window.location.href='http://url.com'`

At the moment I have the following situation which works

```
const [url,setUrl] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
   getUrl()
     .then(x => x.json())
     .then(x => {
        const { result } = x;
        setUrl(result);
      });
  });

<a target="_blank" href={url}>Url/a>
```

Now my need is to change `<a target="_blank" href={url}>Url/a>` to

```
<button onClick={(e): void => { e.preventDefault(); window.location.href={url}}}
```

The problem is I get this error on **window.location**

*Type '{ url: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.*

How do i fix it? Is there a better way to put the sate link on click event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `window.location.href=url` instead of `window.location.href={url}` as the warning suggests.

```
<button
  onClick={e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = url;
  }}
/>
```

`window.location.href={url}` will assign an `Object`: `{url}` to `.href` which of type `string`, you should assign a `string` type.